# How can i use set and get with static private property in php

Tags: php

I would like to keep the value of the static property throught the program, so am using set and get to access a static property.

```
<?php

class Usuario {
    //
    private static $usuarioStatico;
    //
    function getUsuarioStatico() {
        return $this->usuarioStatico;
    }
    function setUsuarioStatico($usuarioStatico) {
        $this->usuarioStatico = $usuarioStatico;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `$this->` on a static property since it's a reference on the object while `$usuarioStatico` is a class property.

use `self::` instead:

```
class Usuario {
    //
    private static $usuarioStatico = 1;
    //
    function getUsuarioStatico() {
        return self::$usuarioStatico;
    }
    
    function setUsuarioStatico($usuarioStatico) {
        self::$usuarioStatico = $usuarioStatico;
    }
}

$u = new Usuario();

echo $u->getUsuarioStatico(); // Output 1
$u->setUsuarioStatico(2);
echo $u->getUsuarioStatico(); // Output 2
```

Comment: Thank you for updating my code... but if I change the page, I lose the value set and get 1 again instead of 2. I would like to keep this value of 2 in all the pages until I unset back to 1.